# Problema com cache de arquivos css e html

Tags: apache

Estou com dificuldades em meu ambiente de desenvolvimento, estou alterando meus arquivos css e html e estes não estão reproduzindo as alterações no navegador.

"Como posso configurar no VirtualHosts do apache2 um hendler que auto-expire os arquivos enviados para o navegador?"

Comment: Veja se isso ajuda: https://gist.github.com/JamieMason/3245483

Comment: vou fazer alguns testes para ver se resolve